# Custom ListVIew and onclick

Tags: android

Here is my code - everything. I did as you told but I still can`t click on nothing. I mean I can click but nothing happens

```
package fixus.core;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import fixus.lib.News;
import fixus.testing.DataInput;

public class NewserActivity extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        DataInput di = new DataInput();
        ArrayList news = di.getNews();

        NewsArrayAdapter naa = new NewsArrayAdapter(NewserActivity.this, R.layout.row, news);
        setListAdapter(naa);
        ListView lv = getListView();

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view,
          int position, long id) {
        Log.i("testy", "I Clicked on Row " + position + " and it worked!");
      }
    });


   }

    @Override
    /**
     * When the user selects an item in the list, do an action
     * @param ListView l
     * @param View v
     * @param int position
     * @param long id
     */
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        final int index = position;

        //You can add whatever you want to happen when you click here

        Log.i("testy", "I Clicked on Row " + index + " and it worked!");

    }


    private class NewsArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
        protected ArrayList items;

        public NewsArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList items) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
            this.items = items;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;

            if(v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            }

            News news = this.items.get(position);
            if(news != null) {
                TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.toptext);
                TextView bt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.bottomtext);

                if (tt != null) {
                      tt.setText("Name: "+ news.getName());
                }
                if(bt != null){
                      bt.setText("Status: "+ news.getUrl().toString());
                }
            }

            return v;
        }
    }

}
```

If you know a good tutorial/example that would show me the good way I would love to see it :)

Comment: Thanks for making his code more readable @Tim Cooper =P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your list activity what you should do is something like the following:

```
public class YourClass extends ListActivity {
    //Your Variables
    ArrayList<Type> yourlist;
    YourAdapterClass adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        yourlist = new ArrayList<Type>();
        this.adapter = new YourAdapterClass(this, R.layout.row, yourlist);
        setListAdapter(this.adapter);
        //you might be able to see if the below works instead of overriding 
        ListView lv = getListView();

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
          int position, long id) {
        Log.i("testy", "I Clicked on Row " + position + " and it worked!");
      }
    });
    }

    @Override
    /**
     * When the user selects an item in the list, do an action
     * @param ListView l
     * @param View v
     * @param int position
     * @param long id
     */
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        final int index = position;

        //You can add whatever you want to happen when you click here

        Log.i("testy", "I Clicked on Row " + index + " and it worked!");

    }

//other methods can go here for you list


}
```

You don't want to have your `onClickListener` inside your `getView(...)` method in the `List Adapter`, that is just where you are suppose modify the way your row looks like (adding buttons, textfields, etc. for each row) instead you want to have the `onClickListener` in a class that extends `ListActivity` that connects to your `Adapter`

Good luck, hope this helped

//Edit (adding more info)

You need to 'add it to your adapter' in the onCreate method (see edited code above) Hopefully that should fix the problem. Let me know if it still doesn't work though. If that doesn't work you can try using the `setOnItemClickListener` code I put in the `onCreate` method instead, if that still doesn't work I would try checking out some tutorials (I'll see if i can find you a good one)

Comment: Now it doesn nothing. I`ve added method as you wrote. Shouldn`t I set a listener or something ?

Comment: When you set the adapter you might want to try using just this instead of NewserActivity.this

Comment: I`ve edited original message. I`ve done everything you said but still can`t do it :/

Comment: I watched few examples and everywhere the onClickListener is added to the element in View like for example button (in examples it is in Activity). In my code the only place where I can do that is Adapter. Tbh I`m getting confused

Comment: I finally got it !! The problem was that i had clickable and focusable property for my my items in row. And I found that when it is set the OnItemClickListener is NOT invoked. Big thanks for your help

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out! and I'm glad I was able to help out some! =) Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

I added this code to my method getView inside my class CustomAdapter.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;

        /* ...Code for holder and so on... */

        row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "ROW PRESSED");
            }
        });

        row.setTag(holder);

        setupItem(holder);

        return row;

 }
```