# Dispatch click to ListView when activity implements OnTOuchListener

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

My activity implements OnTouchListener and it have one ListView inside it.
When user touch over ListView, I need to dispatch ClickEvent to ListView that has OnItemClickListener handler.

How can I do this?

**edit:**

Each list item of listView have onTouchEvent handler.
ListView have onItemClick handler.

```
  @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        float actionUpX;

        switch(event.getAction()){

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            actionDownX = event.getX();
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            actionUpX = event.getX();

            mFlipper = (ViewFlipper) view.findViewById(R.id.view_listitem_flipper);


            if(actionDownX < actionUpX){
                // |--->
                mFlipper.showNext();                
            } else if(actionDownX > actionUpX){
                // <---|
                mFlipper.showPrevious();
            } else {
                    //Click
                    //Need to dispatch itemClickEvent to ListView

                    //view.performClick();  this line causes StackOverflowException 
                    }
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    //Need do an action using position of view

}
```

My list item is a ViewFlipper, when user touch and drag item, ViewFlipper need perform 
showNext or ShowPrevious and an single click have to handled by onItemClick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to click on an item in the list and have something happen you need to do something like the following:

```
public class YourClass extends ListActivity {
    //Your Variables
    ArrayList<Type> yourlist;
    YourAdapterClass adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        yourlist = new ArrayList<Type>();
        this.adapter = new YourAdapterClass(this, R.layout.row, yourlist);
        setListAdapter(this.adapter);

        //you might be able to see if the below works instead of overriding 
        //the OnListItemClickListener farther below
        ListView lv = getListView();

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                Log.i("testy", "I Clicked on Row " + position + " and it worked!");
             }
         });
    }

    @Override
    /**
     * When the user selects an item in the list, do an action
     * @param ListView l
     * @param View v
     * @param int position
     * @param long id
     */
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        final int index = position;

        //You can add whatever you want to happen when you click here

        Log.i("testy", "I Clicked on Row " + index + " and this overriding worked!");

    }

//other methods can go here for you list


}
```

You will also need an adapter class (in my example my adapter class is called `YourAdapterClass`) You can either make this a private class in your ListActivty or a completely new class in its own Java file like the following:

```
public class YourAdapterClass extends ArrayAdapter {
        protected ArrayList items;

        public YourAdapterClass(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList items) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
            this.items = items;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;

            if(v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            }

          //do stuff to your list view row if it is a custom row with multiple 
          //components like text views, image views etc.

            return v;


       }
}
```

Usually this way is used for custom ListViews (lists with custom made rows, but you can use it for a normal view as well)

Hope this helps you at least get started in the right direction.

Good Luck.

(this was an answer I basically gave for another thread similar to this one [Custom ListVIew and onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6553033/custom-listview-and-onclick/6553145#6553145))

Comment: Ok. But each item of my listVew have onTouchEventListener. So, when user CLICK(not drag), the onListItemClick should be called. Ty

Comment: I don't think you want to be using onTouchEventListener because that is usually more for map views, when you have a list and the user 'touches' the list item it is technically a 'click' that is why you want to use the onClick related stuff. I know it is a little confusing but I think you should not have onTouchEventListener for your listView then when the user clicks it should call onListItemClick and you should be able to do whatever action you wanted. Also make sure you don't have the any focusable or clickable items in your list row otherwise the onListItemClick doesn't seem to work.

Comment: So, i need implement 2 behaviors for listItem: 1 - click(switch to another activity). 2 - drag(viewFlipper of listItem show the second Layout for item, showing 4 buttons which each one lauch different activity.

Comment: I haven't really played much with dragging so I don't think I'll be much help for you there =( Sorry.

It seems like because you are listening for the actions of down and up, it seems to make the app ignore the click (which technically speaking is a down and up action made by someones finger) so that could be why you might be able to get one working but not the other.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your activity doesn't need to implement OnTouchListener? Just let the ListView handle the touch event. If that doesn't suit you, then consider passing the touch event to the super class before you process it. That should correctly dispatch the event or tell you if no one handled it.