# Highlight selected cell with background image

Tags: android, android-listview

I am trying to highlight touched cells of my listView. Because the cells have a backgroundimage set I use an onTouchListener for the View of the tableCell to change the ColorFilter.

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601438/dispatch-click-to-listview-when-activity-implements-ontouchlistener) the onTouch Listener seems to conflict with a OnItemClickListener of a ListView.

So is there any easier way to highlight a cell with a backgroundimage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that StateListDrawables can also be created programatically, so I could use a generic approach for setting background pictures.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a list selector property and a drawable file for the state_selected/pressed etc.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that I need a generic approach that can handle whatever is set as background, not just one specifig image